# How to change style according to hidden attribute using scss?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass, styles

Parent reusable component:(settings-panel.component.html)

```
<button>
    <app-svg-icon [iconSrc]="iconSrc"></app-svg-icon>
</button>
<div [ngClass]="position" class="settings-panel" [hidden]="!panelIsVisible">
    <span class="arrow"></span>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

This is my current component(outage.component.html)

```
 <app-settings-panel class="outage-main" iconPath="alert.svg" position="right bottom">
     <div class="outage-panel">
        <div class="outage-heading">
            <span>Notifications</span>
            <span>New</span>
        </div>      
        <span *ngFor="let outage of outageArray">
            <button type="button" class="outage-group-item">
                <span>{{outage}}</span>
            </button>
        </span>
     </div>
 </app-settings-panel>
```

This is my current component scss (outage.component.scss)

```
   :host ::ng-deep app-settings-panel {

        div.settings-panel {
            right:-1px !important;
            top:none !important;
        }

        button{  
            background: #152935!important;      
            padding: 12px !important;
        }
     }
```

So here, in my current component, i'm using the settings-panel component. So whenever `hidden attribute`in parent div is present in parent component, i need to  change the parent button background  to red. If not, i need to change background of parent button to green? I have make changes in current component to do this!

How can i achieve this?

I thought of doing like this, but this syntax is wrong

//So when the div is hidden, i need to make the button background change

```
:host ::ng-deep app-settings-panel div.settings-panel[hidden]{   
    :host ::ng-deep app-settings-panel button {
        background:red;
    }
}
```

If more explanantion is needed , please suggest so that i can edit more clearly.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's a bit confusing... your title mention modifying the css based on `hidden` attribute, but in your question you ask for `open (not hidden)`. And why don't you change the button style from the parent component?

Comment: @David I need to change style when (it's hidden or not hidden) any change in display happens. I'm not doing in parent component because, it's a common resusable component. The above case is only for my current component.

Comment: What's causing you problem? The change detection or jsut where to put the css?

Comment: @David I have modified now. Can you please check now?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

in your outage component, just modify your existing scss

```
:host ::ng-deep app-settings-panel {

    div.settings-panel {
        right:-1px !important;
        top:none !important;

     &[hidden] button //Add this rule
     {
         background-color: red;
      }
    }

    button{  
        background: #152935!important;      
        padding: 12px !important;
    }
 }
```

Just use `host` in your child component

From the parent component, set a `open` class somewhere on `<app-settings-panel`  when the div is open

Then in the child component you can style the button like this

```
:host(.open) ::ng-deep button
{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have modified the question clearly now. Can you please check ?

Comment: I think I understand better now. Can you check updated answer?

Comment: hey Thank you ! I think we're close now. But the button is not present inside the div which has hidden attribute.It is outside the div. Can you check the updated question please??

Comment: From your code it looks like it's inside. Maybe create a simple example on stackblitz